# How to work with checkbox and onChange in React

Tags: reactjs, input, react-hooks, onchange

I'm trying to understand these codes but I'm not sure if I'm understanding right. Please tell me if I'm understanding wrong. I'll list them below.

1. `false` is in the useState variable `isChecked`. (Checkbox is un-checked at this time.)
2. When `handleOnChange` is triggered, `isChecked` will be `true`. (Checkbox is checked at this time.)
3. `isChecked ?` in `{isChecked ? "checked" : "un-checked"}` is `true`. So if the checkbox is checked it will display as "checked" and if it's un-checked, it will display as "un-checked".

```
export default function App() {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);

  const handleOnChange = () => {
    setIsChecked(!isChecked);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      Select your pizza topping:
      <div className="topping">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          id="topping"
          name="topping"
          value="Paneer"
          checked={isChecked}
          onChange={handleOnChange}
        />
        Paneer
      </div>
      <div className="result">
        Above checkbox is {isChecked ? "checked" : "un-checked"}.
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: your understanding is correct and it is working as per your requirement mentioned in question - https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-night-um40ch?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

You have a good understanding of the code. Here's a summary of what's happening:

1. const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false): A state variable isChecked is declared and initialised as false using the useState hook. This means that when the component first renders, the checkbox will be unchecked.
2. const handleOnChange = () => { setIsChecked(!isChecked); }: The handleOnChange function is defined and it uses the state updater function setIsChecked to toggle the value of isChecked between true and false. This function will be triggered when the checkbox is clicked.
3. Paneer: The checkbox is rendered, with the checked attribute being set to the value of isChecked, and the onChange attribute being set to the handleOnChange function. This means that when the checkbox is clicked, the handleOnChange function will be called, and the value of isChecked will be toggled.
4. Above checkbox is {isChecked ? "checked" : "un-checked"}.: The text "Above checkbox is checked." or "Above checkbox is un-checked." is rendered based on whether the checkbox is checked or not. This is achieved using a ternary operator isChecked ? "checked" : "un-checked".

Overall, the code creates a checkbox with a label of "Paneer" and displays "Above checkbox is checked" when the checkbox is checked, and "Above checkbox is un-checked" when the checkbox is unchecked.